# UITableView and Selecting Items

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I am currently creating a simple grouped UITableView that when the user selects for example "Apple" I would like a image I have in my project to be loaded into a Image View of a Apple.

I have seen some examples on the internet but I am trying to see what else is out there.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndeaPath: do?

Comment: Its called right before the cell is displayed.  It is where u make UI changes to the cell, not content changes tho.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to learn here. Detecting table selection (`-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`) and displaying an image in a `UIImageView` (`-setImage:`) are straight-forward operations. Where are you having trouble? What samples have you seen? What about the samples made you want to look for other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Either set the `cell.imageView.highlightedImage`, or in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, change the `cell.imageView.image` from nil to some `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"com.me.foo.cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
    cell.imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(iPadRootViewControllerTableCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Do this if you didnt set the highlightedImage in cellForRowAtIndexPath
    // [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myApple.png"];
}
```

Comment: Would that work if I have 7 different options in my UITableView. Apple, Orange, Banana........

Comment: Yup, it would.  Just use the indexPath.row as the objectForIndex for your array.